# Why searching in BST is faster than Binary search algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I wonder why searching in BST is faster than Binary search algorithm.

I am talking about tree that have (almost) always the same numbers of vectors in sub tree (well balanced.)

I have tested both of them and searching in BST is always faster. Why?

Comment: A binary search algorithm implemented _how_?

Comment: Please post the code you are using for your tests. A lot depends on implementation.

Comment: @San: you could (should) ask the same about the BST if you want to go into the details.

Comment: Which data structure? I think you should insert your code (may be using vector or may be initialization of array or ...)

Comment: By providing an example where binary search is faster than BST, i prove you wrong that "BST is always faster": http://codepad.org/utc0cWEc

Comment: @Dominik: What does an _iterative_  binary search look like?

Comment: BST should be slower merely due to cache impact of including additional pointers in each element and possible non-locality of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both should be about the same in terms of speed. Both are O(log n). The binary search accesses a memory location and make a comparison at every iteration. The BST follows a pointer (which is also a memory access) and makes a comparison. The difference in constants within their big-O complexity should be negligible.

One possible reason might be the fact that you need to perform an extra calculation during every iteration of the binary search. Most implementations have a line like:

```
mid=(high+low)/2;
```

The division operation can be costly compared to integer addition and comparison operations. this might be contributing to the extra performance overhead. One way to reduce the impact would be using:

```
mid=(high+low)>>1;
```

But I think most compilers will optimize that for you anyway.

The BST variant does not need to compute anything, it just compares and follows the appropriate pointer.

Also it might be that you are doing your binary search recursively and your BST query non-recursively making the BST faster. But it is really hard to come up with any specific reasons without looking at your code.

Comment: If you're using signed integers for `high` and `low`, the compiler cannot optimize `(high+low)/2` to `(high+low)>>1` for you unless it can somehow determine that the values are always positive. Thus you should use unsigned types or write the `>>1` version yourself.

Comment: @R..: Didn't know that the compiler couldn't catch that. Now that you point it out, it does make sense that the compiler would not know whether the values overflow or not. Thanks.

Comment: It's not about overflow. The compiler can ignore overflow. It's about the fact that `(-1)/2` is 0 while `(-1)>>1` is -1 (at least according to C's perversion of algebra).

Comment: Yep, there are at least 3 different definitions for division of negative numbers - quite interesting (especially since not all programming languages agree on what to use). But anyhow in case of a binary search algorithm the compiler should be able to reason that the indizes are always >= 0 since it knows that the size of an array has to be >= 0 and the start minimum position is 0 as well. Though I'd hope that anyone here would use the correct version **low + (high - low) / 2**, may not be a problem, but why risk anything?

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to know without looking at the implementation. At their core, they are the same thing.

The BST needs to follow pointers to traverse into the right half, whereas binary search on arrays does arithmetic (e.g. addition and division/shift). Usually, the the binary search on arrays is a little faster because it traverses less memory overall (no pointers need to be stored) and it is more cache coherent in the final stages of the algorithm.

If the array variant is always slower for you, there's probably a glitch in the implementation or (but this is very unlikely!!) the arithmetic is a lot slower than all the memory overhead.

Comment: Looking at the implementation could reveal the answer, it could also tell you nothing. Compiler, platform and CPU also play a role.